# How do I evaluate this sum :$\sum_{n=2}^{\infty}\frac{3^{n}(2^{n-1}-1)}{2^{n}(3^{n-1}-1)}$?.

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series, convergence-divergence

i would like to know how do i evaluate this sum :$$\sum_{n=2}^{\infty}\frac{3^{n}(2^{n-1}-1)}{2^{n}(3^{n-1}-1)}$$.

Note :I used many creterions but i can't determine wether if it is convergent

series .

Thank you for any help

Comment: The main term converges to $\frac{3}{2}$ as $n\to +\infty$, hence it is a divergent series.

Comment: why you are negliged the second term ?

Comment: $$ 3^n*2^{n-1} >> 3^n$$  so"  Jack D'Aurizio" negliged the second term

Comment: $6^n+C = 6^n\cdot(1+o(1))$ as well as $6^n+3^n = 6^n\cdot(1+o(1))$.

Comment: thank you , sorry for this i didn't get attention for common factor

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Consider
$\sum_{n=2}^{\infty}u_n
$
where
$a, b > 1$
and
$u_n
= \frac{a^{n}(b^{n-1}-1)}{b^{n}(a^{n-1}-1)}
$.

$u_n
= \frac{a^{n}(b^{n-1}-1)}{b^{n}(a^{n-1}-1)}
= \frac{a^{n}b^{n-1}(1-1/b^{n-1})}{b^{n}a^{n-1}(1-1/a^{n-1})}
= \frac{a(1-1/b^{n-1})}{b(1-1/a^{n-1})}
\to \frac{a}{b}
$
as $n \to \infty
$.

Since the terms of the sum
tend to a limit,
the sum is unbounded,
since the sum of
$n$ terms
tends to
$n\frac{a}{b}$.